# Single query to return documents sorted by distance based on one documents Id rather than its geopoint

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an index in elasticsearch which contains a Id field and a geopoint.

right now in order to get the nearest documents I have to make two queries, one to get the original document by its id and after that use its coordinates to do a geosort. I was wondering if there is anyway to execute this as a single query.

```
public IEnumerable<RestaurantSearchItem> GetNearbyRestaurants(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            var query = _elasticClient.Search<RestaurantSearchItem>(s =>
                s.Index(RestaurantSearchItem.IndexName)
                .Sort(
                    ss =>ss.GeoDistance(
                        g => g
                            .Field(p => p.Location)
                            .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Plane)
                            .Unit(DistanceUnit.Meters)
                            .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
                            .Points(new GeoLocation(latitude,longitude)))));

            var nearByRestaurants = query.Documents;

            foreach (var restaurant in nearByRestaurants)
            {
                restaurant.Distance = Convert.ToDouble(query.Hits.Single(x => x.Id == restaurant.Id).Sorts.Single());
            }

            return nearByRestaurants;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see a second query in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this in one query; the latitude and longitude used for sorting can't be looked up from elsewhere in the data, so needs to be supplied in the request.

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, the only Elasticsearch query that accepts id of a document as its parameter is [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query, which fetches list of terms for the query from the given document.

But you want to find relevant documents based on location, not exact terms.
This can be achieved with [denormalization of your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html). It might look like storing the list of nearby restaurants in a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/nested.html) field.

In the case of denormalization you will have to pre-compute all nearby restaurants before inserting the document in the index.